# Custom sliders in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, custom-controls, slider

Is it possible to have a custom background and a custom knob for a slider in OSX?  It looks like the original function for assigning different bitmaps has been deprecated, and I don't see any easy way other than creating a complete class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @spudwaffle has it right. Customizing control appearance is usually just an override of a drawing function. Creating a complete class is rarely needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to override `NSSliderCell`'s `- (void)drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect` and `- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)aRect flipped:(BOOL)flipped`.

From the [`NSSliderCell` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSliderCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've created an [LADSlider](https://github.com/Doshipak/LADSlider). That will help you to create a custom slider in OSX fast and really simple.